# explode function return array with serial number

Tags: php, implode

I have an array like this `$arr = Array ("A","E","I","O","U");`

My question is using `implode` function how can I make the output like this

```
1.A
2.E
3.I
4.O
5.U
```

Comment: implode has to use a static delimiter. you'll need to iterate over your array to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each values like this:

```
$arr = array("A","E","I","O","U");
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $key + 1 . ".{$value} <br>";
}
```

This will give you the desired Output as:

```
1.A 
2.E 
3.I 
4.O 
5.U
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    echo $i . '.' . $v . '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

no need to use `implode` function. Just use `foreach` loop to iterate whole array.

Answer (score 1):

use array_walk to traverse the array like this:

```
array_walk($array, function($v, $k)
{
  echo $k + 1 . '.' . $v . "<br>";
});
```